# Windows 10 does not update time after dualboot

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, time

After splitting disk to two partitions and going to dualboot with Ubuntu 15.10 I discovered weird error: When I reboot back to Windows, the time is X hours delayed, where X roughly equals amount of time I have been using ubuntu.

Clicking the clock, then going to settings and switching off/on option "setup time automatically" solves this problem, but I would like to find some automatic solution.

What should I do to fix this forever?

Comment: That's not a windows 10 issue. Windows uses the CMOS clock to set the time, and Linux adds or removes the timezone difference to it. When going back to Windows after using Linux, the clock is either a few hours late or in advance.